# How to use @Query annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am trying to use the @Query to create a custom method in my jpa repository but I am getting the following error at runtime, please help me check it out. Thanks in advance

below is the code

```
public interface OrganizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Organization, Long> {
        
    List<Organization> findByDeleted(Boolean isDeleted);
    
    List<Organization> findAllByDeletedOrderById(Boolean isDeleted);

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM ORGANIZATION WHERE id = :organizationId AND NAME LIKE %:organizationId% LIMIT 1 ", nativeQuery = true)
    Organization findFirstNameByNameLike(@Param("organizationId") Long organizationId, @Param("name") String name);
    
}
```

below is the runtime error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.entity.Organization com.oasis.firsbacklogbackend.repository.OrganizationRepository.findFirstNameByNameLike(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String) but parameter 'Optional[name]' not found in annotated query 'SELECT * FROM ORGANIZATION WHERE id = :organizationId AND NAME LIKE %:organizationId% LIMIT 1 '!
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used organizationId twice instead of name. Like this instead:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM ORGANIZATION WHERE id = :organizationId AND NAME LIKE %:name% LIMIT 1 ", nativeQuery = true)
```